# Is there a way to begin a dialogue from within a dialogue in Microsoft Bot Builder?

Tags: botframework, chatbot

What I am attempting to do is implement a question tree with the Bot Builder. Here's what I have now:

```
bot.dialog('initialDialogue', [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "What can I do for you?");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        userInput = session.message.text;

        switch(initialDialogueParse(userInput)) {
            case "error":
                session.send("I'm not sure what you're asking. I'll figure this out sometime! Try again");
                session.beginDialog('initialDialogue');
            case "changePassword":
                session.beginDialog('changePassword');
            case "deleteAccount":
                session.beginDialog('deleteAccount');
            case "changeEmail":
                session.beginDialog('changeEmail');
        }
        session.endDialog();
    }
])
```

The initialDialogueParse method works and does its job perfectly, the issue is after that. For instance, when I enter a response that prompts the 'changePassword' case I get:

- an "Error: Dialogue[] not found" error in the console
- The bot says the prompt from changePassword
- The bot then says "Oops. Something went wrong and we need to start over.".
- It loops around to initialDialogue again

What I want it to do is basically quit the initialDialogue dialogue, and swap over to the changePassword dialogue. This cycle will then repeat until the line of questioning is done.

EDIT: I don't have breaks in my switch statements. The answer below works, too, but the error was in me not reading the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use session.replaceDialog('your_dialog_option') for all options in your initialDialogue, and when you finish all actions required by that option in his own dialog, you use session.replaceDialog('initialDialogue') to go back to initialDialogue. This way, the cycle will repeat all times that you want.